# Soap APi v2 Get Xml Responce

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I am using http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html soap v2 version . but i need to response in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you responce.

```
$product = array(

    'type'=> "simple",
    'product_id'=> "10736",
    'product_name'=> "Test",
    'product_sku'=> "5432",

     -------------------

);
```

now used below code for convert array to xml.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($product, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
echo "<pre>";print $xml->asXML();
```

result is,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <type>bla</type>
  <product_id>10736</product_id>
  <product_name>Test</product_name>
  <product_sku>5432</product_sku>
</root>
```